# How do you prove that any two integers will always have a greatest common divisor?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I think my book actually prove it by showing that the set of all linear combinations of two integers is a principal ideal of integers. But I can't see how this proves that two integers will always have a gcd. Is there different way of proving this?

Comment: @vadim123 - $\gcd(0,0) = 0$.

Comment: OK, so you need to re-read the definition of $\gcd$.

Comment: @vadim123 "Greatest" should be meant in the divisibility ordering.  In this sense, $0$ is the "greatest" divisor of $0$.

Comment: @vadim123 If we are artificially restricting gcd to nonzero integers, it is far more proper and useful to restrict it to the non-negative integers, on which everybody is happy.  On $\mathbb{Z}$, it is (morally speaking) not unique nor should it be.  In general, the gcd in a principal ideal domain $R$ is not a binary operation on $R$, but rather on the set of principal ideals.  Your definitions, while consistent, are pointless, as their only purpose is to forbid the _correct_ and _useful_ equation gcd(0,0) = 0.

Comment: @mathguy I'd not say that everyone defines the gcd via divisibility (which I agree is the correct definition). Some (definitely not most) people leave $\gcd(0,0)$ undefined. It depends on how you want to *use* the gcd or generalize it.

Comment: I wouldn't call Wikipedia an authority, and Graham, Knuth, Patashnik is a book on computer science. In computer science they define $0^0$ to be equal to 1; that doesn't make it right and very few in the actual field of math (as opposed to computer science) would agree with that definition. In any case: when one speaks of "principal ideals" they no longer talk about integers, they talk about (commutative) rings in general. Most rings aren't ordered in the "usual" sense to begin with. Other than in elementary math, $\gcd$ is ONLY defined by divisibility.

Comment: @vadim123 You're clearly not reading your references, because that book exactly supports what mathman and I have been saying—greatest common divisors, by their definitions, are not unique, yet they are a well-defined concept even when all elements are zero.  They use the divisibility ordering.  They do not require $0$ in their condition to be a GCD domain precisely because having non-zero gcds gives you gcds with zeros as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's see... say the original numbers are $a$ and $b$, and the ideal of all linear combinations is the principal ideal generated by $d$. That is, every linear combination of $a$ and $b$ is a multiple of $d$. This already shows $d \mid a$ and $d \mid b$, because both $a$ and $b$ are (trivially) linear combinations of $a$ and $b$. Conversely, $d$ itself is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ (because it is an element of the ideal it generates), so any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ divides $d$ as well. So $\gcd(a,b) = d$ by definition of $\gcd$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic states that any number $n \geq 2$ can be the product of primes.

Case 1A: $p,q \neq $ 1 or 0. p is divisible by q or q is divisible by p. This yields GCF$(p,q) \gt 1$.

Case 1B: $p,q \neq$ 1 or 0. p is not divisible by q and q is not divisible by p. This yields GCF$(p,q)=1$

Case 2: p or q = 1 or 0. This yields GCF$(p,q)=1$